# xslt for dispaying table with names

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this sample of xml:

```
<row>
  <cell type="editorOnly">
   <note type="firstName">John Adam</note>
   <note type="lastName">Taylor</note>
  </cell>
  <cell type="editorOnly">
    <note type="firstName">Doug</note>
    <note type="lastName">Miller</note>
  </cell>
  <cell type="editorOnly">
    <note type="firstName">Peter</note>
    <note type="lastName">Henderson</note>
   </cell>
</row>
```

I am trying to display it like this:

**Taylor, John Adam, Doug Miller & Peter Henderson (edit.)**

(the surname followed by first name for the **first** cell in the row, and than the first name followed by sur name for the **rest** of the cells).

I have made this xslt, but it dosen't the way I want:

```
<xsl:template match="TEI:cell[@type='editorOnly']">
        <span class="editor">
            <b>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="child::TEI:note[@type='lastName']">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="TEI:note[@type='lastName']"/>
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="TEI:note[@type='firstName']"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </b>
            <span>
                <xsl:text> (edit.)</xsl:text>
            </span>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::TEI:cell[@type='editor']">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="following-sibling::TEI:cell[@type='editor'][position()!=last()]">
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text> &amp; </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
```

What am I doing wrong?

KSR

Comment: Could you post the expected result **as code**?

Comment: Thank you very much. The template is just spot on.

Comment: Is it possible make the same output if the template match "cell[@type='editorOnly']" instead of "row"?

Comment: Perhaps, but it wouldn't be easy nor convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the surname followed by first name for the **first** cell in the row, and
>   than the first name followed by sur name for the **rest** of the cells

I am guessing you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <span class="editor">
        <b>
            <xsl:for-each select="cell[@type='editorOnly']">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="note[@type='lastName']"/>
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="note[@type='firstName']"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="note[@type='firstName']"/>
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="note[@type='lastName']"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position()=last() - 1">
                        <xsl:text> &amp; </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="position()!=last()">
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <span>
                <xsl:text> (edit.)</xsl:text>
            </span>
        </b>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```